# Swift 2.1 Paytm Integration Issue

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift2, xcode7, paytm

I am facing this kind of error: 'PGTransactionViewController' has no member 'initTransactionForOrder'. Can anyone help me out to sort out it.

```
func Pay_btn_Action(sender:UIButton!) {


    var mc: PGMerchantConfiguration = PGMerchantConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
    mc.checksumGenerationURL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumGenerator.jsp"
    mc.checksumValidationURL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumVerify.jsp"

    var orderDict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = NSMutableDictionary() as [NSObject : AnyObject]

    orderDict["MID"] = "WorldP64425807474247"
    orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP"
    orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Retail"
    orderDict["WEBSITE"] = "worldpressplg"
    orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = "1"
    orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = PaymentView.generateOrderIDWithPrefix("")
    orderDict["REQUEST_TYPE"] = "DEFAULT"
    orderDict["CUST_ID"] = "1234567890"

    var order: PGOrder = PGOrder(params: orderDict)

    PGServerEnvironment.selectServerDialog(self.tbl_Payment, completionHandler: {(type: ServerType) -> Void in

         var txnController: PGTransactionViewController = PGTransactionViewController.initTransactionForOrder(order) 

        if type != eServerTypeNone {
            txnController.serverType = type
            txnController.merchant = mc
            txnController.delegate = self
            self.showController(txnController)
        }
    })


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know this specific library, but in general, if this has been adapted to Swift from Objective-C, it should be something like this:

```
PGTransactionViewController(transactionForOrder: order)
```

Comment: Yes i did the same in this way  let txnController = PGTransactionViewController.init(transactionForOrder: order) and it get's solved.Thanks Eric D.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved all the queries.

```
func Pay_btn_Action(sender:UIButton!) {

//Step 1: Create a default merchant config object
    let mc: PGMerchantConfiguration = 
   PGMerchantConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()

   //Step 2: If you have your own checksum generation and validation url set this here. Otherwise use the default Paytm urls        

    mc.checksumGenerationURL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumGenerator.jsp"
    mc.checksumValidationURL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumVerify.jsp"

    //Step 3: Create the order with whatever params you want to add. But make sure that you include the merchant mandatory params
    var orderDict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = NSMutableDictionary() as [NSObject : AnyObject]

    orderDict["MID"] = "WorldP64425807474247"
     //Merchant configuration in the order object
    orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP"
    orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Retail"
    orderDict["WEBSITE"] = "worldpressplg"
     //Order configuration in the order object
    orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = "5"
    orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = ViewController.generateOrderIDWithPrefix("")
    orderDict["REQUEST_TYPE"] = "DEFAULT"
    orderDict["CUST_ID"] = "1234567890"

    let order: PGOrder = PGOrder(params: orderDict)

    //Step 4: Choose the PG server. In your production build dont call selectServerDialog. Just create a instance of the
    //PGTransactionViewController and set the serverType to eServerTypeProduction
    PGServerEnvironment.selectServerDialog(self.view, completionHandler: {(type: ServerType) -> Void in

        let txnController = PGTransactionViewController.init(transactionForOrder: order)


        if type != eServerTypeNone {
            txnController.serverType = type
            txnController.merchant = mc
            txnController.delegate = self
            self.showController(txnController)
        }
    })


}
```

If anyone wants the Swift 2.1 Paytm wallet Integration code into their iOS app can download the whole project from here.
[link](https://github.com/KrishaWeb/Paytm-Wallet-Swift-Integration)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).